# Flutter Error : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get array of images from firestore but i get following errors:

**My Error:**
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

**code:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _store.load_item(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Item> _item = [];
          for (var doc in snapshot.data.docs) {
            var data = doc.data();

            _item.add(Item(
                admin_id: data['admin_id'],
                item_id: data['item_id'],
                item_description: data['item_description'],
                item_price: data['item_price'],
                images: List.from(data['images'])));
          }
          return GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _item.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Stack(children: [
                Image(image: NetworkImage(_item[index].images.toString()))
              ]);
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: Text("Loading....."));
        }
      }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is causing your problem:

```
images: List.from(data['images'])));
```

You aren't receiving  a list,but a string. Make sure it's a list in firebase.

Comment: If it's indeed a list, it's correct. What is the output of `print('data['images'])`?